# CSS Z-fighting on animated semi circle pie charts

Tags: css, html, charts

So I found [this](https://codepen.io/nourabusoud/pen/YXvOVm) codepen example of an animated semi circle pie chart made in pure CSS. I'm trying to use it to make a 'political seat distribution'. As you can see on the edges of the chart in the image below, the color of underlying pie-pieces is coming through on the edges.

I'm not sure if this can be fixed, and if so, how. The effect is visible in both Chrome and Firefox and seems to get worse when I change height and width from pixel based values to vw-units.

I also included a compiled CSS version of the original snippet with a multi-arc example below.

[image: pie chart showing harsh edges on the sides]

The gist of the css that makes the arcs happen is here:

EDIT: I changed it to also use vw's. you can see the edge problem on the end of the middle (yellow) arc, it shows the underlying green arc.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 20px;
}
.container .label-text {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.pie-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 40vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pie-wrapper .arc, .pie-wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  width: 80vw;
  height: 40vw;
  position: absolute;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pie-wrapper:before {
  border: 20vw solid #E8E8E8;
  border-bottom: none;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 40vw 40vw 0 0;
}
.pie-wrapper .arc {
  border: 20vw solid #47CF73;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 40vw 40vw;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.pie-wrapper .score {
  color: #394955;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.arc[data-value="24"] {
  -moz-animation: fill 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fill 2s;
  animation: fill 2s;
  -moz-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  transform: rotate(43.2deg);
  transition: All 5s ease;
  border-color: #47CF73;
}
.arc[data-value="24"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 5px;
}
.arc[data-value="24"]::before {
  background-color: #47CF73;
}

.arc[data-value="65"] {
  -moz-animation: fill 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fill 2s;
  animation: fill 2s;
  -moz-transform: rotate(117deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(117deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(117deg);
  transform: rotate(117deg);
  transition: All 5s ease;
  border-color: #47CF73;
}
.arc[data-value="65"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 5px;
}
.arc[data-value="65"]::before {
  background-color: #47CF73;
}

.arc[data-value="100"] {
  -moz-animation: fill 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fill 2s;
  animation: fill 2s;
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: All 5s ease;
  border-color: #47CF73;
}
.arc[data-value="100"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 5px;
}
.arc[data-value="100"]::before {
  background-color: #47CF73;
}

.arc[data-value="24"] {
  border-color: #FF3C41;
}
.arc[data-value="24"]::before {
  background-color: #FF3C41;
}

.arc[data-value="65"] {
  border-color: #FCD000;
}
.arc[data-value="65"]::before {
  background-color: #FCD000;
}

.arc[data-value="80"] {
  border-color: #FCD000;
}
.arc[data-value="80"]::before {
  background-color: #FCD000;
}

.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.legend span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 20px;
}
.legend span.green {
  background-color: #47CF73;
}
.legend span.orange {
  background-color: #FCD000;
}
.legend span.red {
  background-color: #FF3C41;
}

@-moz-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border-color: #FF3C41;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-color: #47CF73;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border-color: #FF3C41;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-color: #47CF73;
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border-color: #FF3C41;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-color: #47CF73;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pie-wrapper">
     <div class="arc" data-value="100"></div>
     <div class="arc" data-value="65"></div>
     <div class="arc" data-value="24"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's hard for me to see, but I think this may work?

```
.pie-wrapper .arc { background-color: white; }
```

Comment: I changed my original question to use vw-sizings. You can see the tearing on the outward edge near the end of the yellow arc, it shows 1 pixel of green underneath.

I tried your solution, but  this only fixes the problem on the inside of the arc, not on the outside. Also, I'd like to keep the background transparant because in the actual code there's an image background underneath.